# Having problem with prediate logic

Tags: logic, predicate-logic

Suppose that the UoD (Universe of Discourse) is {A, B, C, D, E, F, G} which are softwares and I want to make the statement that "At least four softwares have a bug".

Let P(x) be the predicate that " x has a bug" then, I know that:

∃ x : P(x)

would meant that at least one of the elements of the UoD satisfy P(x), that is, only one software out of all in the UoD has bug.

But for the statement, "At least four softwares have a bug", I can not solve it. Please help. Anyone.

And what about "At most four softwares have a bug"?

Comment: Before working with quantifiers, try to work with constants. Suppose $A$, $B$, $C$, and $D$ are divisible by 2. How would you formalize that statement?

Comment: That's now what I'm trying to figure out. I modified the question a little bit for better understanding.

Comment: I understood what you meant, but I'm trying to give you some hints about how to do it. It's easier to first formalize "These four softwares have a bug" and then proceed to formalize "There are at least four things that have a bug".

Comment: That's precisely what I can not figure out. I 'm not supposed to know which of these softwares possess that bug. And then solve express in logical form as general.

Comment: *Hint:* What does $\exists x\,\exists y: x\ne y,  P(x), P(y)$ say?

Comment: ∃a∃b∃c∃d : (a ≠ b) & (b ≠ c) & (c ≠ d) & (d ≠ b) & (d ≠ a) & (c ≠ a), P(a), P(b), P(c), P(d).

Is this the solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll develop my hint a bit more.

Suppose you knew that four softwares have a bug, say $A$, $B$, $C$, and $D$. Let $P(x)$ mean "x has a bug". You could then symbolize the situation with the following formula:

> $P(A) \wedge P(B) \wedge P(C) \wedge P(D)$

But that's not quite you want, since this formula mentions specific individuals, and you need something that does not mention specific individuals. So one natural attempt would be to quantify into that formula, resulting in:

> $\exists x \exists y \exists z \exists w (P(x) \wedge P(y) \wedge P(z) \wedge P(w)$

But this would not solve your problem, because this formula would still be true if only one software had a bug (just check the satisfaction clause for the existential quantifier). In the formula using constants, that was not a problem, because we're assuming that each constant refers to a different object. That does not happen here, as the variables could all refer to the same object. So you need to say that the $x$, $y$, $z$, and $w$ that satisfy this formula are all different. How do you say that?

Comment: Awesome! Thank you so much. You made my day. I was stuck at this problem since like 15 to 20 minutes.

Comment: No worries. Can you accept the answer, so it's not in the unanswered queue anymore?

Comment: But what if we have to say that, "There are at most four softwares that have the bug".

Would it be translated as:

I'm taking three for simplicity.

∀a, ∀b, ∀c: ((a ≠ b) & (b ≠ c) & (c ≠ a)), P(a), P(b), P(c). Answer this too, please. =)

Comment: @user3813179 - No, because that statement would imply (among other things) that $a \not = a$, and would thus entail a contradiction. What you need here is, in a sense, the opposite of what we had above: whereas before we needed a formula saying that the variables ranged over different objects, now we need a formula saying that, if there is a further variable, it ranges over the *same* objects.

Comment: ∀a, ∀b, ∀c: ((a = b) & (b = c) & (c = a)), P(a), P(b), P(c) would mean that we have exactly three objects that are equal to each other, and thus, these three objects only satisfy our propositional function?

Comment: @user3813179 - Actually, the above formula says that there is only one object that is $P$, as they are all equal. But you're getting closer. As I said, you need to say that, if there is a fifth object that satisfies the predicate, then it is either equal to the first, or equal to the second, etc.

Comment: Should it be something like this?

∀a, ∀b, ∀c: ((a = b) OR (b = c) OR (c = a)), P(a), P(b), P(c)

May be, it is the solution but can you please explain its significance?

Comment: @user3813179 - Almost. I'd give you a little help here. If you want to say that at most two things are $P$, you say $\forall x (P(x) \rightarrow \forall y(P(y) \rightarrow \forall z (P(z) \rightarrow (z = y \vee z = x))))$. Intuitively, this formula says that, if there is a third thing that is $P$, then this third thing is actually either the first, or the second; i.e. there at most two objects satisfying the predicate.

Comment: Got it. Thanks again. =)

Comment: @user3813179 - Don't mention it. Btw, if you need to say that there are *exactly* $n$ things, just remember that *exactly* $n$ is the same as "at least $n$" and "at most $n$", i.e. just combine the two strategies.

Answer (score 1):

Don't know about Michael's string of $\ne$'s. May I suggest:

$\exists w,x,y,z:[P(w) \wedge P(x) \wedge P(y) \wedge P(z) \wedge w \ne x \land w\ne y \land w\ne z \land x\ne y \land x\ne z \land y\ne z]$

**Hint for at most 4:**

For exactly 2 softwares with a bug:

$\exists a,b:[a\ne b \land \forall c:[P(c)\iff c=a\lor c=b]]$

Answer (score 0):

Four softwares with a bug: $\exists w \exists x \exists y \exists z (P(w) \wedge P(x) \wedge P(y) \wedge P(z) \wedge (\neg((w = x) \lor (w = y) \lor (w = z) \lor (x = y) \lor (x = z) \lor (y = z)))$

Comment: What about "At most four softwares have a bug"?